# ListBox forcing update of items

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, .net-3.5

I created a `ListBoxItem` where I have a property `Name` and override `ToString()` to give back name. That works nicely when I add new items.

But now I need to force the `ListBox` to update the labels when I change the name of my ship. I thought Refresh or Update would do that but that doesn't work.

I might be missing something very easy here.

```
public class ShipListBoxItem
{
    public ListBox Parent { get; set; }

    public ShipType Ship { get; set; }

    public ShipListBoxItem()
    {
        Ship = new ShipType();
    }

    public ShipListBoxItem(ShipType st)
    {
        Ship = st;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Ship.Name;
    }

    public void UpdateListBox()
    {
        Parent.Refresh(); //My problem is here. Update doesn't work either.
    }

    public static ShipListBoxItem AddToListBox(ListBox lb, ShipType ship)
    {
        ShipListBoxItem li = new ShipListBoxItem(ship);

        li.Parent = lb;

        lb.Items.Add(li);

        return li;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works when I tested it. You don't need to refresh to show an added item. I called it like this: ShipType s1 = new ShipType();             s1.Name = textBox1.Text;             ShipListBoxItem.AddToListBox(this.listBox1, s1);

Comment: It works fine for adding items not for modifying them.

Comment: Your UpdateListBox() takes no arguments, how would it update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 ListBox.RefreshItems()
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.refreshitems(v=vs.90).aspx)

EDIT: You can use an extended class like this:

```
public class FooLisBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
{
    public void RefreshAllItems()
    {
        RefreshItems();
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   (listBox1.Items[0] as ShipListBoxItem).Ship.Name = "AAAA";
   listBox1.RefreshAllItems();
}
```

Comment: I went your way. I will post the full code in a later post when I ironed out the code for making sure the selected item remains selected without getting a circular code problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `List<T>` as the `DataSource` for the listbox it is pretty easy to have changes to  items show up.  It also means there is no real reason to have a special class for adding a `ShipListBoxItem` to a ListBox, your basic `Ship` class may work:

```
class ShipItem
{
    public enum ShipTypes { BattleShip, Carrier, Destroyer, Submarine, Frigate };

    public ShipTypes Ship { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ShipItem(string n, ShipTypes st)
    {
        Name = n;
        Ship = st;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", Ship.ToString(), Name);
    }
}
```

The form related stuff:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add some ships
    Ships = new List<ShipItem>();
    Ships.Add(new ShipItem("USS Missouri", ShipTypes.BattleShip));
    Ships.Add(new ShipItem("USS Ronald Reagan", ShipTypes.Carrier));
    lb.DataSource = Ships;
 }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // change a ship name
    lb.DataSource = null;           // suspend binding
    this.Ships[0].Name = "USS Iowa";
    lb.DataSource = Ships;          // rebind
    lb.Refresh();
}
```

As an alternative, you can also tell the Listbox to use a specific property for the display using `DisplayMember`:

```
lb.DataSource = Ships;
lb.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This would use the Name property in the listbox instead of the `ToString` method.  If your list is changing a lot, use a `BindingList` instead.  It will allow changes to the list show up in the ListBox as you add them without toggling the DataSource.

Comment: For future references This works but looked unprofessional, (Read ugly) to me.

Comment: Toggling the datasource *is* a pain, which is why I mentioned the BindingList.  It depends on how dynamic the underlying data is whether it is worth it or not.

Comment: I need to get my data via LINQ. Internally my data is a derived Dictionary<string, ShipType>. The trouble with this way is my list updates visibly 3 times.. making a derived listboxClass gives me a lot more control and is (in the long run) more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.

Mostly, thanks Jose M.

I ran into a problem however. RefreshItems() triggers OnSelectedIndexChanged()

so my overridden class looks like this

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public bool DoEvents{ get; set; } // Made it public so in the future I can block event triggering externally

    public MyListBox()
    {
        DoEvents = true;
    }

    public void RefreshAllItems()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        DoEvents = false;
        base.RefreshItems(); // this triggers OnSelectedIndexChanged as it selects the selected item again
        DoEvents = true;
        ResumeLayout();
    }

    // I only use this event but you can add all events you need to block  
    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoEvents)
            base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }
}
```